# function not working on append string

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onclick, append

I wrote function while clicking a class name. and its works fine.  but when i am append a tag with same class name the function is not working on that class.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("p").append(" <b class='test'>Appended text</b>.");
        });

        $(".test").click(function(){
            alert(12);
        });

    });
</script>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<ol>
    <li class="test">List item 1</li>
</ol>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
```

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dLgetr0w/

Comment: Final Solution is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dLgetr0w/1/

Answer (score 0):

That's because jQuery binds the event at the time you call `$(".test").click(...)`. You need to bind it separately:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b class='test'>Appended text</b>.")
          .click(function(){alert(12);});
});
```

Comment: It will alert '12' twice while click on the "List item 1".

Comment: Fixed. But I'd go with the solutions in the duplicate questions.